# CX_Freeze import error on Windows and ZMQ

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyzmq

I've a python program that uses ZMQ. I want to Freeze it so everyone can use it as executable. This is my setup.py

```
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
includes = ["sip", "re", "zmq", "PyQt4.QtCore", "atexit", "zmq.utils.strtypes", "zmq.utils.jsonapi", "encodings.hex_codec"]

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup (
    name = "prueba",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Esto es una prueba",
    options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes }},
    executables = [Executable("Cliente.py", base = base)])
```

When I run this on Linux it works perfect and my program runs OK, but when I do so on Windows I get the Following Error when I execute the .exe file:

```
from zmq.core import (constants, error, message, context,
File "ExtensionLoader_zmq_core_error.py", line 12, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module cannot be found
```

Also, when CX_Freeze is working I can notice the following lines:
    Missing modules:
    ? zmq.core.Context imported from zmq.devices.basedevice
    ? zmq.core.FORWARDER imported from zmq.devices.monitoredqueuedevice
    ? zmq.core.QUEUE imported from zmq.devices.monitoredquedevice
    ? zmq.core.ZMQError imported from zmq.devices.monitoredquedevice

I've been trying to figure out this problem for an hour or two, it seems it may be related with a DLL it should be importing and it isn't. Some DLL that ZMQ needs to work, but I cannot find which one is it.

Comment: Managed to make it work. I did the following:

First I added the following lines to the script
    test = list()
    test = sys.path
    test.append("C:\Python27\zeromq-pyzmq-962ca4d\zmq")

    options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes , "path" : test}}

This way I made sure it was looking to the right place, then I found a file called zmqlib.dll somewhere on the computer, and copied it into the zmq folder and then it started working

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding:

`['zmq','zmq.utils.garbage','zmq.backend.cython']`

To the packages, then renaming `zmq.libzmq.pyd` to `libzmq.pyd`

Comment: This is a 3 years old post. This project has been shutted down so I don't have any way to test it. You are a bit late :/

Answer (score 0):

You may have to explicitly add one or more modules to your includes. If it IS a DLL issue though, I usually use Dependency Walker to figure it out. You can get it free here: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

It occasionally gave me a false positive, but overall it's almost always helped.

Comment: Will give a look to this, but I wrote in my comment how to fix it